# UIViewController under UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UINavigationController` and a `UIViewController` as its root view controller.

```
let rootVC = Page1ViewController()   // extends UIViewController
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootVC)
presentViewController(nav, animated: true) { () -> Void in
}
```

The problem is that the content of the rootVC appears under the navigation bar. I tried:

```
nav.navigationBar.translucent = false
```

this worked but I want the navigation bar to be transparent and I want the content of the rootVC not appear behind the navigation bar.

I also tried:

```
nav.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None
```

but this does not change anything.

**How can I get a transparent navigation bar where the content scrolls under it when scrolling but when loading the content should not appear under the navigation bar?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
nav.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None
```

And add this line in your viewDidLoad from Page1ViewController

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge.None
```

Hope it helps. Let me know if it doesn´t work and I will help you.

Comment: This works but now I have a black background behind the statusbar. Can you fix that too?

Answer (score 2):

To address your issue of a blackbox now appearing underneath your `UINavigationBar` you need to set the presentation context properly. Try setting `definesPresentationContext` on your `UINavigationController` to `NO`. This will then use the `UIWindow` or parent of your `UINavigationController` as the presentation context.

Comment: I did ``nav.definesPresentationContext = false`` but there is no effect.